# Magento createBlock : Fatal error : Call to a member function toHtml()

Tags: magento-1.9, template

I have been working on adding custom options on product category listing page. w.r.t [here.](http://catgento.com/2012/02/09/adding-configurable-product-options-to-category-list-in-magento/)

My code for display options `list.phtml`

```
<div class="actions">
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form" <?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php if ($_product->isConfigurable()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_type_configurable', array('template'=> 'catalog/product/view/type/configurable_category.phtml'))->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

I am getting error like.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on null in app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 154
```

where i am creating a mistake please correct me why the `configurable_category.phtml` template file is not loading.

please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use below syntex

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_type_configurable')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/type/configurable_category.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Hello Jaimin i used your syntax but i am getting another error like `Call to a member function getTypeInstance() on null in`